# Calulating percentage table column in SQL

Tags: sql

How can I calculate the percentage of a whole column? Currently what I've written so far only gives me the percentage of each row. I want only 1 row with the total percentage. I want to sum all the values to calculate one percentage.

```
SELECT TOP 1000
       CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), CAST(Passed AS DECIMAL(10, 2))
        / ( Actual ) * 100) AS Percent
FROM    Audits
WHERE   
        MONTH(TransActionDate) = MONTH(GETDATE())
GROUP BY Actual
     , Passed
      , transactiondate
ORDER BY TransActionDate DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `AVG()` and remove the fields from the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT AVG(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), CAST(Passed AS DECIMAL(10, 2))
        / ( Actual ) * 100)) AS Percent
FROM Audits
WHERE MONTH(TransActionDate) = MONTH(GETDATE())
```

If you need `TOP 1000`, then use a subquery:

```
SELECT AVG(Percent)
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1000
       CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), CAST(Passed AS DECIMAL(10, 2))
        / ( Actual ) * 100) AS Percent
    FROM Audits
    WHERE MONTH(TransActionDate) = MONTH(GETDATE())
    ORDER BY TransActionDate DESC
    ) t
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think it was as simple as doing 'AVG()'.